# Prolog Parsing Output

Tags: parsing, prolog, nlp

I'm doing a piece of university coursework, and I'm stuck with some Prolog.

The coursework is to make a really rudimentary Watson (the machine that answers questions on Jeapoardy).

Anyway, I've managed to make it output the following:

```
noun_phrase(det(the),np2(adj(traitorous),np2(noun(tostig_godwinson)))),
verb_phrase(verb(was),np(noun(slain)))).
```

But the coursework specifies that I now need to extract the first and second noun, and the verb, to make a more concise sentence; i.e. [Tostig_godwinson, was, slain].

I much prefer programming in languages like C etc., so I'm a bit stuck. If this were a procedural language, I'd use parsing tools, but Prolog doesn't have any... What do I need to do to extract those parts?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Prolog, the language is the parsing tool. Use the [univ (`=..`) operator](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node81.html#subsec.l9.termstructure) to do term inspection:

```
% find terminal nodes (words) in Tree
terminal(Tree, Type, Item) :-
    Tree =.. [Type, Item],
    atomic(Item).
terminal(Tree, Type, Item) :-
    Tree =.. [_, Sub],
    member(Node, Sub),
    terminal(Node, Type, Item).
```

Now get a list of all nouns with `findall(N, terminal(Tree, noun, N), Nouns)` and get the `nth1` element.

Comment: Hi, I really don't understand... What is N in findall? I've tried to Google etc. but it says it's an Object... There are no objects in Prolog... =S

Comment: @Motig: `N` is just some variable. `findall` collects all the `N` such that `terminal(Tree, noun, N)` in `Nouns`.